# Can't set initial value of Bootstrap 4 Radio Button

Tags: angular

I'm having some difficulty setting the initial value of a radio button. In my component, I create the form and provide the initial value during `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...,
  showInDirectory: [
    true,
  ],
});
```

I would like the radio to be initially set to `true`. Here is the relevant template code:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input formControlName="showInDirectory" [value]="true" type="radio" id="directoryTrue" name="showInDirectory" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="directoryTrue">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input formControlName="showInDirectory" [value]="false" type="radio" id="directoryFalse" name="showInDirectory" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="directoryFalse">No</label>
</div>
```

However the "true" radio is never initially selected. I have tried using string values for true/false, 1/0 and it still won't work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Pengyy There was another exception error that was getting swallowed by stale cache in Chrome. Got that sorted out and my code works as expected now. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" [checked]="true">
```

You have to use the directive selected for it to be initially selected. There might be any boolean expression inside like [checked]="myVar == myOtherVar" from your component.

Comment: This throws an error: `Can't bind to 'selected' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`

Comment: @Brandon did you import the FormsModule in Your App.Module?

Comment: Yes, I have both the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` imported in my module.

Comment: Isn't the property called `checked` (instead of `selected`)?

Comment: I got it figured out. The *actual* problem was that another exception was getting swallowed and the radios were un-checked as a side effect. My original code is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code it seam work :

```
    <div [formGroup]="form">
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input formControlName="showInDirectory" [value]="true" type="radio" id="directoryTrue" name="showInDirectory" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="directoryTrue">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input formControlName="showInDirectory" [value]="false" type="radio" id="directoryFalse" name="showInDirectory" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="directoryFalse">No</label>
</div>
</div>
```

form implementation :

```
form:FormGroup;
  constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
    this.form = fb.group({
      showInDirectory: [ true]
    });
  }
```

[example at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2eq3zn)